# How to start a thread for specific task and run for at most 5 seconds in Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating an API.
Demo code is on [Pull-data-demo-code](https://github.com/jjnnzb/pull-data-demo).

Related bean classes:

```java
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Response {
    private Integer code;
    private String message;
    private JSONObject info;
    
    public static Response success(JSONObject data) {
        return Response.builder().code(200).message("success").info(data).build();
    }
    
    public static Response error(JSONObject data) {
        return Response.builder().code(500).message("fail").info(data).build();
    }
}
```

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ResultBean {
    private Long id;
    private Long parentId;
    private String publishTime;
    private String title;
    private String content;
    private List<ResultBean> children;
}
```

DataController is like:

```java
import com.example.demo.entity.Response;
import com.example.demo.service.DataService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin
public class DataController {
    
    @Resource
    private DataService dataService;
    
    @PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/data/analyse")
    public Response pullDataController(@RequestParam(value = "keyword") String keyword) {
        return Response.success(dataService.analyseData(keyword));
    }
}
```

DataService is like:

```java
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;

public interface DataService {
    /**
     * Analyse data with keyword submitted from client.
     *
     * @param keyword keyword
     * @return the analysed result as json
     */
    JSONObject analyseData(String keyword);
}
```

DataServieImpl is like:

```java
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONArray;
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONObject;
import com.example.demo.entity.ResultBean;
import com.example.demo.service.DataService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class DataServiceImpl implements DataService {
    
    /**
     * Mock third-party api path.
     */
    private static final String THIRD_PARTY_API_PATH = "http://***.com/api/v1/data";
    
    @Override
    public JSONObject analyseData(String keyword) {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        // TODO pull data and save to database for at most 5 seconds.
        pullData(keyword);
        // analyse data
        List<ResultBean> resultBeanList = fetchDataAndAnalyse(keyword);
        result.put("data", resultBeanList);
        return result;
    }
    
    private void pullData(String keyword) {
        List<ResultBean> resultBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
        String response;
        try {
            response = IOUtils.toString(new URL(THIRD_PARTY_API_PATH + keyword), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            JSONObject json = JSON.parseObject(response);
            if (json != null) {
                Integer num = json.getInteger("childrenNum");
                String subKeyword = json.getString("subKeyword");
                // raw data, can be converted to class and save to database.
                JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data");
                saveRawDataToDatabase(data);
                if (num != null && num > 0) {
                    // Iterate for more data
                    pullData(subKeyword);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("error message:{}", e.getMessage());
            log.error("error detail:{}", e.toString());
        }
    }
    
    private void saveRawDataToDatabase(JSONArray data) {
        if(data != null && data.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i);
                // ResultBean resultBean = jsonObject.toJavaObject(ResultBean.class);
                // dataDao.insert(resultBean);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private List<ResultBean> fetchDataAndAnalyse(String keyword) {
        List<ResultBean> list = new ArrayList<>(100);
        // Read data from database
        // List<ResultBean> list = dataDao.query(keyword);
        // process list, handle parent-children relation and return result.
        return list;
    }
}
```

As you can see in DataServiceImpl,

> pullData(String keyword)

is a *recursive function*, so it can be quite **time-consuming**. How to restrict the running time of this function to at most 5 seconds?

Comment: Five seconds is enough for pulling sufficient data for analysing for this API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a maximum execution time for a method/thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500003/setting-a-maximum-execution-time-for-a-method-thread)